# Multiple Selection disable in datagrid in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm working in `wpf` and I am using below data-grid:

```
<DataGrid Name="dgUseCaseList" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Row="0" CanUserAddRows="False" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False" Height="620" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectionMode="Single" >
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="30">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                                    <CheckBox Name="chkSelectAllUseCases" Click="chkSelectAllUseCases_Click" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <CheckBox Name="chkSelectUseCase" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected,Mode=TwoWay}" Click="chkSelectUseCase_Click"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Header="UseCaseId"   Binding="{Binding Path=UseCaseId}">
                                <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                                        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding UseCaseDescription}" />
                                    </Style>
                                </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                            </DataGridTextColumn>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
```

But still I am able to select multiple check-boxes. How to disable this. (I want to select just one checkbox. On selection of next checkbox,the previous one should get unchecked)

Answer (score 0):

Try RadioButton instead of CheckBox.

`<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
     <RadioButton GroupName="group1" Name="chkSelectUseCase" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected,Mode=TwoWay}" Click="chkSelectUseCase_Click"/>
    </DataTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>`

You can customize RadioButton's Template if you want.

`<Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                            <Grid>
                                <CheckBox
                    IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
                                Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    IsHitTestVisible="False" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                                <CheckBox
                IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
                            Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"

                Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Opacity="0"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>`